# Explanation asked about AngularJS fiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a few questions about this fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/rvdww/6/)

This is the Javascript code of this Fiddle where I have some questions about:

```
function Main() {
    this.friends = [{
        name: 'John',
        phone: '555-1212',
        age: 10,
        date: '11 June 2011'},
    {
        name: 'Mary',
        phone: '555-9876',
        age: 19,
        date: '12 June 2011'},
    {
        name: 'Mike',
        phone: '555-4321',
        age: 21,
        date: '13 July 2011'},
    {
        name: 'Adam',
        phone: '555-5678',
        age: 35,
        date: '14 May 2011'},
    {
        name: 'Julie',
        phone: '555-8765',
        age: 29,
        date: '15 June 2011'}];
}

Main.prototype = {

    sort: function(item) {
        if (this.predicate == 'date') {
            return new Date(item.date);
        }
        return item[this.predicate];
    },

    sortBy: function(field) {
        if (this.predicate != field) {
            this.predicate = field;
            this.reverse = false;
        } else {
            this.reverse = !this.reverse;
        }
    },

    reverse: false
};
```

1) I noticed the the author of the Fiddle uses a function as a `Controller` instead of using `app.controller(...)` and then uses `[controller].prototype`. Is it recommended to use this approach? I know I can't ask which way is better, because I have some feeling that is about personal flavour.

2) In the `sort` function I see the (key)word `predicate`. What does this mean? Where does this comes from? I've never seen this before.

3) In the HTML part of this Fiddle I noticed this line: `ng:repeat="friend in friends.$orderBy(sort, reverse)`. A not so difficult line, but am not familiar with the syntax `$orderBy()` notation. Do you always have access to this method? Where does this method comes from?

Comment: Regarding question 2 & 3, have a look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Regarding #1, you are right, it is merely a personal decision and there are no official recommendations for one or another approach (AFAIK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) this approach is bad because you don't have access to dependency injection in controller and in real world use it'll be useless. But for fast and dirty demo it's kinda works.

2) predicate comes [from here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

3) if you look [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ng/filter) you will see that filter and orderBy are angular internal filters. And if you look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) and [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) you will see that there is no such notation. It works but it may stop work at any moment and it's only works because of abuse of side-effect of implementation. So it's breaking of conventions. Not needed as it seems. Hard to understand to someone like you or me.

So it's just bad code from my perspective. Better to stay with conventions and best practices than implement things like this.

Comment: Main.$inject['anythingHere']

Comment: Ok, now I know this way to use it. Not sure I planing to do so because my code may be seen by someone other than browser.

Comment: @SergeyMoiseev Thanks for answering my questions. Just to make sure in point 2, is 'predicate' just a var on `$scope`? So it could be just called 'foo'?

Comment: Predicate is just var outside of scope. In controller. All you need to know about this var is in function sortBy. If it's not set on moment of calling this function it'll be set and reverse will be set to false. In case it's set but not with current value of field parameter same story. And if it set with current value of field parameter only reverse will be changed to different.

Answer (score 2):

It is just useful when you using that pattern.  That pattern is useful when doing some tricky data modeling or controller inheritance. Though, most of the time I personally use the array DI pattern.

[Minko's Blog Post](http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/) should clear things up.  Also note that under the heading "[Explicit Dependecy Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)" someone slipped in this little note: "Best Practice: Use the array annotation shown above."

PS: *I have seen some add the a resolve function onto the end of the controller.  Then calling that resolve function in the app.config with the $routeProvider -- (It is a lot cleaner but slightly more confusing.  As @Sergey Moiseev pointed out, if you are working as a consultant then you may lean more on the readability side.  Though, if you have a dev team it is something that you guys can sit down and talk about.*